# Enter/Exit of unit cube representable as 4 numbers?

Tags: mathematics

In the paper [Real-time Reflection using Ray Tracing with Geometry Field](http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~mueller/papers/EG06_geomfield.pdf)
, it mentions this:

> A ray is represented
>   by its two intersection points (in,out) with the bounding box
>   of the surface. Hence, the geometry field is a 4 dimensional
>   function.

Having two $3D$ points gives 6 values: $A=(A_x,A_y,A_z), B = (B_x, B_y, B_z)$.

How is it that those 6 values, which are on the surface of a unit cube, can be represented with only 4 numbers?

Edit: the best I can think of is to convert each point to spherical coordinates and throw away the length, effectively converting these points to points on a unit sphere.  That way involves some trig operations though. Is there a better way that uses less computation?

Comment: UV-mapping the surface?

Comment: Hrm yeah I guess that's true if you have   a unique range of u and v per face!

Comment: 2 time 2 angle pairs? See the third rotation about the own axis is not needed to represent a arrow in any direction.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too with the spherical coordinates. You don't need roll! But getting the angles takes some trig.  However, this lets you do a ray intersection against a generic object as a table lookup so maybe the trig ops aren't a bad trade off.  Nathan Reed's idea doesn't have that though which is interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3D object surface is 2D domain and can thus be parametrized with a 2D function. In case of a unit cube you could parametrize the surface for example by mapping each 6 faces to a 2D image strip. So if you know two points of the ray that intersects the cube, you can define it with 4D function using the parametrization